# 辞書型においてkeyが重複する場合,上書きをせずに連結する方法について

Tags: python

python始めたばかりの初心者です。

環境:Python 2.7.6

現在複数の辞書型配列をマージしようと試みているのですが、keyが同じのため上書きされてしまい困っています。

つまり

```
dic  = {'A':'1', 'B':'2'}
dic1 = {'A':'3', 'B':'2', 'C':'4'}
```

この2つの辞書型配列があったときに足し合わせて

```
dic_rev ={'A':'1,3', 'B':'2', 'C':'4'}
```

としたいのです。

Comment: 分かる方何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: お二人ともご丁寧に別解までつけてお返事ありがとうございます！新たな関数も勉強できるいい機会となりました本当にありがとうございました！

Answer (score 5):

複数の辞書型配列の value をマージすると、[`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) を使用すべきだと思います。

```
from collections import defaultdict

def merge_dict_values(*dicts):
    r = defaultdict(set)
    for d in dicts:
        for k, v in d.iteritems():
            r[k].add(v)
    return r

dic  = {'A':'1', 'B':'2'}
dic1 = {'A':'3', 'B':'2', 'C':'4'}
dic_merged = merge_dict_values(dic, dic1)
print dic_merged
# defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'A': set(['1', '3']), 'C': set(['4']), 'B': set(['2'])})
```

こうして、各辞書型配列を合併しました。あとは、`set` 型の値を連結して、文字列にします。

```
dic_rev = {k: ','.join(v) for k, v in dic_merged.iteritems()}
print dic_rev
# {'A': '1,3', 'C': '4', 'B': '2'}
```

上記の解決には、`set` を使いましたから、連結した値の順序を保証できません。

各パラメーターの順序と同じしたいなら、以下のような、`list` で格納すべきです。

```
def merge_dict_values(*dicts):
    r = defaultdict(list)     # list に変更し
    for d in dicts:
        for k, v in d.iteritems():
            if v not in r[k]: # この値がない場合追加します
                r[k].append(v)
    return r
```

Answer (score 2):

「マージ」でやりたいことが不明確ですが、以下のコードで期待する結果が出せそうです。
同じ値の場合にカンマで連結しないようにしています。

```
>>> dic  = {'A':'1', 'B':'2'}
>>> dic1 = {'A':'3', 'B':'2', 'C':'4'}
>>> dic_rev = {}
>>> for k in set(dic) | set(dic1):
...     vl = []
...     if k in dic:
...         vl.append(dic[k])
...     if k in dic1 and dic1[k] not in vl:
...         vl.append(dic1[k])
...     dic_rev[k] = ','.join(vl)
...
>>> dic_rev
{'A': '1,3', 'B': '2', 'C': '4'}
```

Answer (score 1):

別解として `reduce` を使う方法などを。

```
def merge_dict(d, k, v):
  if k in d:
    if d[k] != v:
      d[k] += ',' + v
  else:
    d[k] = v
  return d

reduce(lambda d, (k, v): merge_dict(d, k, v), dic.items() + dic1.items(), dict())
=> {'A': '1,3', 'C': '4', 'B': '2'}
```